# Are these Hebrew inscriptions actually "correct"?

Tags: in-the-beginning-the-bible-stories

I'm watching episode 15 of Osamu Tezuka's [*In the Beginning: The Bible Stories*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In_the_Beginning:_The_Bible_Stories) out of curiosity. In both this episode and episode 23, we see what appears to be the stone inscriptions of the ten commandments, in something that looks like Hebrew. (Click for bigger image.)

[image: tablet from episode 15] [image: tablet from episode 23]

I was wondering if these are actually reasonably "correct" Hebrew inscriptions, given that I've seen placeholder texts in animated books that had nothing to do with the actual in-universe meaning of the books (e.g. RPG-related material in alchemy books in the 2003 FMA).

I would assume that this *is* correct, but I had extremely little success trying to cross-check with either text in Hebrew [here](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0220.htm) or [here](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0505.htm), particularly since I don't know Hebrew.

Might anyone know the answer to this?

Comment: Note: if this is off-topic; drop me a line and I'll remove the question. I also wasn't sure what the appropriate tag would be.

Comment: I think this would be better off on a Hebrew text stack... but I don't know that exists... maybe the http://judaism.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking of that but wasn't sure. If someone intiates a close vote, I'll join in, but if not, I'll keep it around for now.

Comment: I don't know that this is necessarily a question for [judaism.se] - that would be kind of like going to [christianity.se] with a screenshot of "Our father who art in heaven, hallowed be thy name" and asking if it was a Christian thing. I think Madara knows Hebrew, so if he happens to see this, he could probably venture an answer.

Comment: Provisionally tagged with [tag:in-the-beginning] for lack of a better tag.

Comment: first picture yes, on the second one the words don't make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The left hand picture, is the exact original Hebrew text from the ten commandments in the bible, but only the first two or three words from each commandment. It is very usual to depict only the first few words on Hebrew drawings of the Tablets.

```
"I am the L-d your G-d
You shall not have another god over me
You shall not carry G-d's name [in vain]
Remember the day of [Shabbath...the rest is off the photo edge]"
```

The right hand picture is complete gibberish.

Answer (score 2):

They are ask real words (in the top picture, it's kind of hard to read the second one).  I don't really know how to prove it though.  The big, bold words mean vertical, no, no, and trapped in that order going down.  The rest is religious about g-d.  Sorry if that doesn't answer the question fully.

Comment: I got the same meanings from Google Translate, which makes me suspect that it's hard to know if it's coherent and related to the decalogue without knowing / looking up additional Hebrew. Thanks though!

Comment: From my bay knowledge of Hebrew obtained in the moments that I was actually paying attention/awake in Hebrew school, most of it seems well put together (grammatically).